# 3d flip animation inside a fragment

Tags: android, image, animation, android-fragments, flip

I want to implement 3d flip animation on two image views inside a fragment.
I have two images of a human body i.e. front and back. What I want is to flip the front image to the back when user clicks on a button. And all these things are inside a tab fragment.

I am searching for this from more than 1 hour but didn't get anything useful.
I got some results related to hoe to implement 3d flip animation with fragments inside it but didn't get anything related to what I want.

Please can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking something like this.

```
 image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
 image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
 image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);



image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
  if (isFirstImage) {       
  applyRotation(0, 90);
  isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;

  } else {    
  applyRotation(0, -90);
 isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
 }
 }
});      




private void applyRotation(float start, float end) {
// Find the center of image
final float centerX = image1.getWidth() / 2.0f;
final float centerY = image1.getHeight() / 2.0f;

// Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
// The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
final Flip3dAnimation rotation =
   new Flip3dAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY);
rotation.setDuration(500);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFirstImage,    image1,   image2));

if (isFirstImage)
{
image1.startAnimation(rotation);
} else {
image2.startAnimation(rotation);
}

}
```

you can find the complete source from here 
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Hope it may help you.Good luck

Comment: Great. It helped me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Flip" animations are fairly straightforward with [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html). An example implementation could be:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "rotationY", 0F, 360F);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animator.start();
```

This should flip your `ImageView` and give you somewhere to start.

**Edit:** You could perhaps flip the first `ImageView` by `180F` (so that it effectively becomes invisible), then use an `AnimatorListener` to start another flip on the second `ImageView`, also by `180F`, so it appears one image has transitioned into the other.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it inside a fragment? Can you help me with some tutorial? So that it would be easy for me to understand and implement it

Comment: @Arpita What do you mean by "inside a fragment"? Using `ObjectAnimator` on an `ImageView` inside a `Fragment` shouldn't be any different to inside an `Activity`?

Comment: Its like I have implemented sliding tabs with navigation drawer. And I want to add 3d flip animation between images inside one of the sliding tab fragments.